# C# How to serialize/deserialize an Object to/from Dictionary<string,Object> to save/load it in Couchbase.lite

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, couchbase, couchbase-lite

If I want to store data as Document in Clouchbase.lite is has to be in the form of Dictionary like this:

```
var properties = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        {"type", "list"},
        {"title", "title"},
        {"created_at", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString ("o")},
        {"owner", "profile:" + userId},
        {"members", new List<string>()}
    };
var rev = document.PutProperties(properties);
```

How can I automatically create such a Dictionary from any C# object? 
If I understand the couchbase.lite documentation this process does not to be recursive, just on the first level of my object fields and properties.

How can I recreate my objects from such a dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this not a full answer to my question, but it solves the problem for now. I came to the solution of putting the whole object into the Dictionary that is handed to Couchbase.Lite:

```
    var c = new TestClass() {TestString = "SimpleStringfield", TestDate = DateTime.Today,TestStringProperty = "TestStringPropertyContent",
                              TestStringList = new List<string>(new string[] { "item1","item2","item3"})};


    var manager = Manager.SharedInstance;
    var db = manager.GetDatabase("test_database");
    if (db == null)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("--------------------------Could not open Database");
    }

    var doc = db.CreateDocument();
    var properties = new Dictionary<string,Object>() { {"type","day"}, {"day",c} };

    var rev = doc.PutProperties(properties);

    var docread = db.GetDocument(doc.Id);
    JObject testobject = (JObject)docread.GetProperty("day");

    var o = testobject.ToObject<TestClass>();
}
```

At the end o contains the same values as c.

I want to point out the warning that Jim Borden gave me to this approach:

> I will always assert that the "right way" is the way that works. The
>   fact that the library uses JSON .NET internally is an implementation
>   detail, though. If that were to change for some reason then this way
>   would break. I also have a feeling that if the class were more complex
>   than your example than it would break as well. We are currently
>   designing a cross platform specification to do just what you want to
>   do (save classes directly to the database without converting to a
>   dictionary first). This will be a slow process though because there is
>   a lot of thought that needs to go into it (not just for C#, but for
>   Java and Objective-C as well). For example, how to serialize a class
>   that has a property which references back to it, etc. I know JSON .NET
>   already does this, but I don't want to start exposing JSON .NET into
>   the public API because eventually it should be switchable (in case
>   JSON .NET does not work for whatever reason on a platform).

Comment: The official ticket is here: https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-net/issues/275 Pity, that it has been put on ice again recently

Answer (score 0):

I know you are talking about automatic, but I needed the individual fields of my class to be exposed so I can index them and run mapped queries. So I specified all my query-able objects to follow this interface:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    string Id { get; set; }

    IDictionary<string, object> ToDictionary();
    void PopulateFrom(IDictionary<string, object> prop);

}
```

And typically implemented as follows:

```
public class Club : IEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Place { get; set; }
    public long ClubId { get; set; }
    public string Access { get; set; } = "read";
    public List<ClubMember> Members { get; set; }

    public void PopulateFrom(IDictionary<string, object> prop)
    {
        Name = prop.GetOrDefault<string>("name");
        Country = prop.GetOrDefault<string>("country");
        Place = prop.GetOrDefault<string>("place");
        ClubId = prop.GetOrDefault<long>("club_id");
        Access = prop.GetOrDefault<string>("access");
        Members = ParseMembers(prop["members"]);
    }


    public IDictionary<string, object> ToDictionary()
    {

        return new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "club_id", ClubId },
            { "name", Name },
            { "country", Country },
            { "place", Place },
            { "access", Access },
            { "members", Members}
        };
    }

}
```